# Exit Function in Powershell causes Unhandled exception error

Tags: forms, powershell, error-handling, exit

i have recreated this error on a simple PowerShell Form and it keeps happening in every code i create.
i want to exit the entire program using the exit button. but i get the exception.
can anyone help?

```
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
    
    $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
    $Form.Text = "press Exit to Quit"
    $Form.minimumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 200)
    $Form.maximumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200, 200)
    $Form.TopMost = "True"
    $Form.ShowInTaskbar = "True"
    $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
    $Form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D
    
    $Exit = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button;
    $Exit.Text = "Exit"
    $Exit.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100, 50)
    $Exit.add_click({Exit}) 
    
    
    
    
    $Form.Controls.Add($Exit)
    
    
    $Form.ShowDialog()
```

also the error text is:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.Management.Automation.ExitException: System error.
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ThrowInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
   at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0 arg0)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(ScriptBlockClauseToInvoke clauseToInvoke, Boolean createLocalScope, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, List`1 variablesToDefine, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClass57_0.<InvokeWithPipe>b__0()
   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action action)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe, InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Boolean propagateAllExceptionsToTop, List`1 variablesToDefine, Dictionary`2 functionsToDefine, Object[] args)
   at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeAsDelegateHelper(Object dollarUnder, Object dollarThis, Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `$Exit.add_click({Exit})` is supposed to do.

```
$Exit.Add_Click({
    $Form.Close()
})
```

Comment: this will only close the form. if i have more code beyond the form it will keep running will it not?
to clarify, if i have several forms running and i want the user to be able to close the entire program from this form by pressing the exit button then i need the exit function to work. or am i missing something?

Comment: @user3593721 You're using `$Form.ShowDialog()`. That's a blocking call - no code is running beyond the form, all code waits for the form to return. You can put and `Exit` on the next line if you want. Or you make `$Form.ShowDialog()` the last line of your script, and it will exit naturally when after form is closed.

Comment: To clarify: "the next line" is not the one after `$Form.Close()`, it's the one after `$Form.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: so if i  have $FORM1 and it contains $FROM2 i can tell the exit button in $FORM2 to close the first form and it will terminate both ?

Comment: ...if it was my code, would explicitly close all open forms instead of hoping that `Exit` will handle it. If you want a better answer, post code that reproduces your situation (multiple forms) and triggers the error. (That means: "write new code from scratch that does *nothing* but reproduce the error", not "post your entire current code")

Comment: i understand. i thought as much. just wanted to understand the underlining essue.
thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @user3593721 I'm not sure about the underlying issue, to be honest. I suppose it's some sort of timing problem between the thread that runs the form, and the thread that runs your script. I've never seen it happen in my code, but then again, I've never tried to use `Exit` in a button click handler, because it simply feels wrong for me. My assumption is, if you tear down your forms cleanly, you can side-step the issue.